# Whats the analogy for when something dawns on you or gets bigger as you go on with your life (kind of like a problem)

Tags: idiom-requests, analogy

I'm writing a paper and trying to find an analogy for when something gets bigger as time goes on. For context, I'm writing about how as you progress further into your 20s, the fear of failure becomes more apparent. There's an analogy (or idiom?) that's used for this kind of thing and it's at the tip of my tongue but I can't remember it.

Comment: Figurative [*grew like a cancer*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22grew+like+a+cancer%22) is a common usage. But so are lots of other expressions. There is no "right" answer here.

Comment: ...but perhaps [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) fits the bill as regards the "fear of failure" element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ***snowball effect***:

> a situation in which something increases in size or importance at a faster and faster rate:
>
> - The more successful you become, the more publicity you get and that publicity generates sales. It's a kind of *snowball effect*. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowball-effect))